# Table class not working in css / html

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Trying to add a table into the footer of a webpage, and this specific table needs to be 100% wide, black background. Have coded the css and html as below, and doesn't seem to recognise it at all. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```css
table.sign {
    width:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    align:center;
    border: none;
    padding: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="sign">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Content will go here.</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: seems like it works fine. `align` isn't a valid css property though.

Comment: @MichaelCoker are you 24/7 on stackoverflow?? loool

Comment: I made a fiddle and it works fine although @Michael Coker is right.  I'm guessing you want to use `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: Also, the `padding` property is wrong; `none` is not a valid value. And it won't do what you want, since a table has 0 padding to begin with. You probably wanted to assign it to `table.sign td` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I re inputted all the coding and it seems to work fine now... no idea what was up with it before! It's been niggling me for two hours and I just couldn't see *anything* wrong with it, so resorted to checking here! Sorry to waste time!

Comment: @Samuel Oh, maybe a cached version of the old stylesheet. If that happens, just clear the cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using text-align: center; on the td instead of the table

```
table.sign {
    width:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `padding: none;`  not a valid property . You should change it to `padding:0;` also text-align should be set for td not on table tag

Comment: Edited to reflect your comment @Jayakrishnan